# How to use rio command line from rasterio?

Tags: mapbox, rasterio

I want to use rasterio and rio-color plugin.

I used pip for installing rasterio and rio-color and afterwards when I want to run "rio", I see this:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rio", line 7, in <module>
    from rio.manage import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rio/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .app import create_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rio/app.py", line 11, in <module>
    from rio.setup import configure_app
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rio/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .core import db
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rio/core.py", line 14, in <module>
    from flask_user import UserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_user/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin as LoginUserMixin, make_secure_token
ImportError: cannot import name make_secure_token
```

What should I do?

Comment: Rio is part of rasterio therefore simply install rasterio

Comment: @gene Ok, thank you. But then how can I reach this command line interface? How to run it?

Answer (score 2):

as gene says, rio is part of rasterio, the python package, so it's a **pip install**

To set up in a python virtual env, run the following. I find I need to install numpy separately first, rather than trying to pull it in as a dependency of rasterio (if I just install rasterio, it complains it can't find the numpy header files)

```
mkdir /tmp/build
cd /tmp/build
pyvenv venv  # or venv venv, depending on python version
. ./venv/bin/activate
pip install numpy  # this can take a long time, so be patient
pip install rasterio
pip install rio-color
rio
```

If all goes well, you should get a usage string.

Using **pip search** shows the various plugins you can bring in if you need to:-

```
pip search rio-
rio-joydivision (0.0.1)  - Lines will tear us apart
rio-clip (0.0.2)         - Clip a geo-aware raster to the bounds of another.
rio-hist (0.3.0)         - Histogram matching plugin for rasterio
rio-toa (0.3.0)          - Top Of Atmosphere (TOA) calculations for Landsat 8
rio-mucho (0.2.2)        - Windowed multiprocessing wrapper for rasterio
rio-alpha (0.5.1)        - A replacement for pxm-alpha
rio-metasay (1.2.0)      - Skeleton of a Python package
rio-pansharpen (0.2.0)   - rio-pansharpen
rio-rgbify (0.3.0)       - Encode arbitrary bit depth rasters in psuedo base-256 as RGB
rio-cloudmask (0.2.0)    - Cloud masking plugin for rasterio
rio-merge-rgba (0.2.0)   - rio merge alternative optimized for RGBA
rio-color (0.4.0)        - Color correction plugin for rasterio
rio (0.3.2)              - RESTful event dispatcher based on celery.
rio-mbtiles (1.3.0)      - A Rasterio plugin command that exports MBTiles
rio-client (0.3.0)       - Client for Rio.
```

Comment: thank you, steven. I updated my question with response when trying to run rio, do you know where the problem could be?